# Custom thumbnail pager affects all sliders on page - Bx-Slider v4

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, custom-controls, thumbnails, bxslider

I recently built a site that calls the bx-slider multiple times on a div by class name. Using the normal pager works fine, but I get an error when using a custom pager with thumbnails. It seems that navigating the slider with the "pagerCustom" option turned on will affect all sliders on the page.

Here's a reduced test case for you to look at: http://codepen.io/DavidVII/full/jhoIc

Click on the thumbnails and see how both sliders change.

If you'd like to fork my CodePen, check out this link here: http://codepen.io/DavidVII/pen/jhoIc

I made a new issue on the plugins github page, but I thought I'd post here since I've always had luck on stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like code advertising to me

Comment: What's code advertising, @Joshua? This was a real question from 2 years ago.

Comment: Bletch. I forgot to check the date. Not sure why 2 year old question ended up in review.

Comment: Ya, I totally forgot about this until someone tried to answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my actual answer for anyone who happens to come across this. Codepen example [here](http://codepen.io/DavidVII/pen/zKCcB).

Here's the JS needed to make this work:

```
var sliderSets = $('.sliderWrap');

function initSliders(targetSlider, targetPager) {
  $(targetSlider).bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: targetPager
  });
}

$(sliderSets).each(function() {
  var targetSlider = "#" + $(this).children('.bxslider').attr('id');
  var targetPager = "#" + $(this).children('.bx-pager').attr('id');

  initSliders(targetSlider, targetPager);
});
```

I'm essentially looping through all elements with my target CSS class and calling the `.bxSlider` method on it.

Please note that this code is from 2 years ago so the BxSlider code might have changed. I'm answering this since I never posted the actual answer when I came up with this solution 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you've initialized both the sliders with a single class. It should be done with two separate classes, like `.bxslider1` and `.bxslider2`

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="bxslider1">
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="bxslider2">
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $('.bxslider1').bxSlider();
    $('.bxslider2').bxSlider();
</script>
```

Comment: That would be one way of approaching it. However, I needed something a little more dynamic. I posted my solution above. It's quite simple really.